# Powershell execute files one by one

Tags: powershell

I want to execute several files one by one with an exe. For this I use a Get-ChildItem with an Out-Gridview that I put in a variable to choose the files I want to run later :

```
$choose = Get-ChildItem 'path' | 
          Out-GridView -Title "Select your files" -OutputMode Multiple
```

To run all files one by one, I thought I would use this code :

```
$choose |
Foreach-Object{
    xexec $choose
```

`xexec` is the name of the executable but it doesn't work. It only executes the first file among those selected.

[image]

I don't understand why.

Comment: First your loop is missing the closing brace. Second $choose is the entire list that you’re trying to loop over, you should definitely not reference it in the loop. Since it’s a foreach-object loop you need to reference $_ or $psitem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `ForEach-Object` body you'll want to use the `$_` (or `$PSItem`) automatic variable to refer to the current pipeline item:

```
$choose | Foreach-Object { xexec $_.FullName }
```